# python iterate though json array of various length

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the values of nested a (a, a1, aa) when [results][x][a] 'x' can be various lengths?

I've made up/simplied my code below so it shorter than the real code and hopefully makes sense. I get results back then I query  [results][0][a], but I need to throw all the various x values into one list instead of getting just one.

Made up example JSON FROM API QUERY

```json
{
    "things": {
        "results": [
            {
                "A": "a",
                "B": "b",
                "C": "c"
            },
            {
                "A": "a1",
                "B": "b2",
                "C": "c3",
                "D": "d4",
                "E": "e5"
            },
            {
                "A": "aa",
                "B": "bb",
                "C": "cc",
                "D": "dd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```py
# CODE EXCERPTS
try:
    thingurl = requests.get("POINTING TO API URL")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:

thing = thingurl.json()


if "a" in query:                     #THIS IS HERE BECAUSE SOMETIMES I DONT CARE ABOUT SOME ELEMENTS                                                 
    try:
        a = thing["results"][0]["a"] #WORKS and grabs 1 thing but need to grab x things
        querylist.append(a)     

    except:
        ipsecname = "N/A" 
        querylist.append(a)
```

Comment: What is `query` variable?

Comment: Is your goal here to grab `x<=` items from the json object at the specified level?

Comment: Maybe iterate over `thing['results']` like ```a = list(record['a'] for record in thing["results"])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop over `results` list. Then you have dictionaries, which also support loops over the `.items()`

```
collector = []
response = thingurl.json()
results = response["things"]["results"]
for i, result in enumerate(results):
  for key, value in result.items():
    if key == 'a':   # example filter
      print(i, key, value)
      collector.append(value)  # example of storing all results in one list
```